# Magento - How call customer attribute in CMS?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9

I want to know how can I call a `custom customer attribute's`  to my CMS.

I tried something like : `{{var customer.custom ('attribute_code')}}` but It's not working.

I hope I expressed myself well :)

Thank you.

Comment: hello, I allow myself to raise the question again :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use that syntax in CMS blocks or pages. You could use a block with some code to get your customer. To insert a block into a CMS page or static block use the following syntax:
`{{block name="<your_block_name_in_layout>" type="<your_block_type>" template="<your_block_template>"}}`
And to get the current customer object in your block you can use the session object:
`Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();`
Depending on how much custom logic you need to implement in your block, you could probably get away with just using a `core/template` block instead of having to define your own block class.